# how to split string by first new line

Tags: php

```
$str = "lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit";
```

How to get first line (`lorem`) as a first variable and `ipsum dolor sit` as a second one.

```
$arr = explode("\n", $str);
$first = $arr[0];
$second = ??? (need `ipsum dolor sit` here);
```

Comment: `unset($arr[0]); $second = implode(' ', $arr);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$pos = strpos($str, "\n");
$first = substr($str, 0, $pos);
$second = substr($str, $pos+1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Explode has a 3th parameter $limit:

```
list($first, $second) = explode("\n", $str, 2);
```

If you also wish to remove the new lines in $second:

```
$second = str_replace("\n", "", $second);
```

Comment: and where is the limit paremeter in your list function?

Comment: Updated the function

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the explode command.

```
$str = "lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit";

list($first, $second) = explode(PHP_EOL, $str, 2);
$second = str_replace(PHP_EOL, ' ', $second);
var_dump($first, $second);
```